# Skip xslt transformation if there is a particular node with a particular property

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to skip the xslt transformations if there is a particular node having a specific attribute value.

SAMPLE XML 1 :

```
<root>
<div class = "noEdit"/>
<name value= "ABC"/>
<address value= "ABC"/>
</root>
```

SAMPLE XML 2 :

```
 <root>
<div class = "Edit"/>
<name value= "ABC"/>
<address value= "ABC"/>
</root>
```

So Now I have these two XML's, I do not want to apply XSLT transformation in case of Sample 1 but apply in case of Sample 2. Condition is determined based on the value of class attribute of div tag. My Sample XSLT currently is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
<xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@ | node()">
<xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-template select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
<xsl:template match="name" >
    <TransformedName><xsl:value-of select="value"/></TransformedName>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="address" >
  <Transformedaddress><xsl:value-of select="value"/></Transformedaddress>
</xsl:template>
```

The above XSLT works in both cases. 1 solution is to put a preceding clause for DIV on both name and address template  matching but this will be an overhead and a code duplication as I have too many nodes like address and Name in the original XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="/root[div/@class='noEdit']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will intercept the `root` element in your first example and stop any further templates being applied, resulting in an output that is identical to the input.

---

Note that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="value"/>
```

should be:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
```

Comment: If i add <xsl:template match="/root[div/@class='noEdit']" /> in my xslt, output for Sample xml 1 is coming out to be blank. I want the output to be same as the input, containing all the original tags and their attributes.

Comment: "*I want the output to be same as the input*" I don't think this can be understood from your question. Anyway, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am fairly new to XSLT and i am struggling a lot in understanding the flow of the language. Can you suggest me some resources(apart from w3 and tutorials point, i have gone through them) for building up an understanding for the language ?

Comment: " 'I want the output to be same as the input' I don't think this can be understood from your question. ", sorry my bad